# Why doesn't os.system ignore SIGINT?

Tags: python, linux

I am reading Linux System Programming.

When introducing the `system(command)` function, the book states that during execution of the `command`, `SIGINT` is ignored.

So, assuming that `os.system` is just a wrapper of the underlying system function, I try the following:

loop.py

```
while True:
      print 'You should not be able to CTRL+C me ;p'
```

test_loop.py

```
   import os
   os.system("python loop.py")
```

Now that I'm executing `loop.py` with `system`, I'm expecting SIGINT to be ignored, but when I use CTRL+C on the running program it still get killed.

Any idea why `os.system` differ from the `system()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SIGINT` is ignored by the application that calls `system` (for as long as `system` is executing). It's not ignored by the application that's spawned by `system`. So if you hit CTRL+c, that will abort the execution of `loop.py`, but not of `test_loop.py`. So if you add some code after the call to `system`, you'll see that that code will execute after you press CTRL+c.